# Javascript ie 9 Seek bar Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to update currentTime when user click on seekbar it works on Chrome an Firefox but on IE9 I am getting Error: DOM Exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR (1).

```
$('#progress').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var percent_width = (e.clientX - offset.left) / parseInt($('#progress').width())*100;
    var number = percent_width.toFixed(2);
    var time = parseInt(vidPlayer.videoObj[0].duration) / 100 * number;
    console.log(time.toFixed(2));

    vidPlayer.videoObj[0].currentTime = time.toFixed(2);
});
```

I've changed code.

Comment: `e.clientX - offset.left` will return a number. Why call `parseInt` on it? `parseInt` is for converting **strings** into (integer) numbers.

Comment: Is this related to your video object or not (i.e. does the error still occur when you remove your currentTime set?). Because Im curious whether vidPlayer.videoObj[0] actually returns what you want... If its not a video object it will error.

Comment: Have you debugged all the terms in that calculation to see that they are reasonable?

Comment: TJ Crowder - I added your suggestions - see above - but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are setting the value of currentTime outside the range of your video? I only see you calculating the percentage of where the user clicked on the bar, but I am not seeing you actually applying the percentage to the length of the video. Because of this, if your video is only 20 seconds long but you click on 78% of the bar, you will try to move to the 78th second of the video, resulting in an out-of-range error.

You could try to add the following:

```
var time = vidPlayer.videoObj[0].duration / 100 * number;
```

Comment: I've changed code as You suggest but still no luck I am getting nice decimal second value and also still the same error.Code above is updated.It works fine on chrome and firefox

Comment: Weird. I made about the same implementation this week and tested it through browserstack and got no such error... DO you have any special modes enables in IE (like quirks, maybe, accidentally...?)

Comment: browser Mode IE9 Doc Mode IE9 standards. I am testing it on node.js http-server but I think doesn't matter

Comment: Any chance you could test this locally? Its only javascript and a video file so you should be able to have a quick local look to see if that makes a difference. It shouldn't, but its better to be sure...

Comment: I've tested it locally and it works fine.But I also tested on Xampp and it's the same issue like on Node -> SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR (1)